# $dateToString returns null with $group in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, datetime, group-by, mongodb-query, tostring

I am trying to do group by using an id field,datetime field and project the sum of values and date field.

```
db.getCollection('driver_collections').aggregate([
{$group : { _id: {driverid:"$driver_id",day:{ $dayOfMonth: "$time_in"},
                  month:{$month:"$time_in"},year:{$year:"$time_in"}},
    amountCollected : {$sum:"$total_collection"}}    
    },{
       $project: {
          yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$time_in" }},
          amountCollected : 1
       }
   }])
```

I used above query and got the result as

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "driverid" : "58014ce1f39e0f9dc40000b2",
        "day" : 30,
        "month" : 10,
        "year" : 2016
    },
    "amountCollected" : 2094.0,
    "yearMonthDay" : null
}
```

I need to get yearMonthDay as

> "yerMonthDay" : "2016-10-30"

When I use **$dateToString** without $group it works fine. What did I miss here.

Comment: It's because you don't have the field `time_in` in your immediate pipeline after the `$group` stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a $time_in in your firststage

```
 db.getCollection('driver_collections').aggregate([
    {$group : { _id: {driverid:"$driver_id",day:{ $dayOfMonth: "$time_in"},
                      month:{$month:"$time_in"},year:{$year:"$time_in"}},
    "time_in" : {$first : "$time_in"},
        amountCollected : {$sum:"$total_collection"}}    
        },{
           $project: {
              yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$time_in" }},
              amountCollected : 1
           }
       }])
```